# flutter: Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build when trying to get SharedPreference instance

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I have a requirement where I need to get the code for the condition from `sharedPreferences` and so for that I was doing the below which is working but is consider a bad practice or I should say flutter is pushing warnings.

```
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (langCode == null) {
      setState(() {
        langCode = "${_prefs.get('langCode')}-${_prefs.get('countryCode')}";
      });
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

normally I would have created `async` funtion and call it in `initState()` but it's also giving the same error.

If I don't use `stateState()` in `didChangeDependencies()` the `langCode` value is not set and I get `flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null`.

what is the best solution to avoid the below error in my case ?

```
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

thank you for going through my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if you dont want to use async function you want to remove only null error just use 
 null avoid operator 
  "${_prefs?.get('langCode')}-${_prefs.get('countryCode')??""}";
```

Or you can use like this

```
Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
 getData()
}

getData()async{
   final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
   String auth =   prefs.getString('auth');
   String uid =    prefs.getString('uid');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling shared preference in starting of your app, then you have to wait for initialization, as said in documentation-[link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html)

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // above line must be called before runApp();
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Then you can you use in other Widget either stf or stl. If answer was helpful, upvote it.